# Proof that as a sample size grows, its mean gets closer to the average of the whole population

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

I think it is common knowledge that as a sample size grows, the probability of its mean, $\overline{X}_n$,  getting closer to the average of the whole population, $\mu$, increases, i.e.,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:desire}
    \forall \epsilon \in {\rm I\!R},\, n_1 > n_2 \implies \rm{P}(|\overline{X}_{n_1} - \mu| < \epsilon) \leq \rm{P}(|\overline{X}_{n_2} - \mu| < \epsilon)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    \overline{X}_{n}={\frac {1}{n}}(X_{1}+\cdots +X_{n}) \;,
\end{equation}

I have seen this concept being justified with the law of large numbers (LLN) but, to my understanding, the convergence specified by the (strong) law of large numbers only characterizes $\lim_{n\to\infty} \overline{X}_n$:
\begin{equation}
    \rm{P}\big(
        \lim_{n\to\infty} \overline{X}_n = \mu
    \big) = 1 
\end{equation}
And does not specify anything about finite numbers of observations.

So, my question is can \eqref{eq:desire} be derived (e.g. from the LLN or the CLT) or is there any law that states something similar to it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the sample mean 'getting closer' to $\mu$ from your definition, since by the unbiasedness of the sample mean we have that $E\left[\bar{X}_n\right]=\mu$ for all $n\geq 1$. Perhaps, you mean that the variance decreases strictly w.r.t. $n$ (we can show that the variance is inversely proportional to $n$ by writing out $\text{Var}(\bar{X}_n)=n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{Var}(X_i)=n^{-1}\text{Var}(X_i)$ for IID $X_i$). When the $X_i$'s are not independent, things get a little more complicated (but variance should still decrease in most cases).

Comment: What you mean by "proof"? In many cases, there will be a finite probability of the average from a smaller sample being closer to the mean than the one from the bigger sample, if the sizes are finite. This probability will tend to zero as the size of the bigger sample grows.

Comment: You have to be careful since the $\bar{X}$ terms are random variables, and it's easy to construct situations where at least one possible sample mean from a smaller sample is closer to the population mean than at least one possible sample mean from a larger one. (For example: a sample of size one that selects a unit whose value is exactly the population mean, versus a sample of size 10 that selects units that are all smaller than the population mean).

Comment: If you flip a fair coin two times, the expected sample proportion of heads is $\frac12$ and you get this exactly half the time.  If you flip a coin $999999$ times you never get exactly $\frac12$ as the sample average, so in this example your assertion is wrong half the time.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback, I have just corrected the innacuracies in the question. @JeanDaviau, the dependency of the variance on 1/n seems like a good starting point to answer my corrected question but I am not sure how to go from there.

Comment: Isn't this effectively what the weak law of large numbers states? (It's not an exact match to the original question, but very similar) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakLawofLargeNumbers.html